# How to style arrow in antd tooltip like this

Tags: tooltip, antd

I have tooltip component created with `antd` library.

I would like to change arrow style to something like that.

[image]

```js
import { Button, Tooltip } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const TooltipOK = () => (
    <>
        <Tooltip placement='topLeft' title="Cool Tooltip" color='purple' getPopupContainer={(triggerNode) => triggerNode}>
            <Button>Cool Text</Button>
        </Tooltip>
    </ >
);

export default TooltipOK;

const StyledTooltip = styled.div`    
    .ant-tooltip-arrow { // arrow wrapper
        right: 0;
        left: initial;
    }
    
    .ant-tooltip-arrow-content { // arrow itself
        background: white;
    }

    .ant-tooltip-inner { // tooltip
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: 1px solid #D04A02;
        color: black;
    }
`
```